# Perform an intermediate revision dump in subversion repository

Tags: svn, fsfs

Hi how are you doing? I have a repository of 60850 svn revisions where by accident 120gb of files were uploaded. To be more specific, the 60660 revion is the heaviest. I was investigating to eliminate this amount with the following tools:

1 - Perform a dump with filtering revisions ***svnadmin dump -r*** and then load to the new repo.

2 - Perform a dump and then filtering with ***svndumpfilter*** and placing the path where these files are located. And then also load the new repo.

I was researching to edit the revision files but I know that they are more likely to break than fix.

I understand that deleting files from a version control system is not the idea since we make sure we can revert when we need it. But these files are not required to be hosted on the server and take up space on it.

Can you suggest any other ideas or ways to do this task?

From already thank you very much.

Regards!

PD: svn versión 1.7.14 (r1542130)

Comment: Why did you tag this question with [berkeley-db]. Do you think that your repositories use BDB backend? What Subversion version do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Already modify the necessary and add version of svn

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried (many years ago), with much older svn versions, the procedure that you mention using `svnadmin dump` is the proper way to proceed. IIRC, the revision numbers are not stored in the dumps (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html).

This way you will reduce the size of the repo. But unless you are running short of disk on the server, the should be no performance issues. Subversion is extremely good at working with absurdely high volume repos with all kind of unnecessary, huge file collections, regardless of whether they are binary or proper text files. The one I work on daily is an example of that. It takes one morning to do a checkout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer butcher. The dump works perfect but when doing a load without the revision it detects that it is missing and does not finish the process. I read that you have to use the --incremental but it fails the same.
What do you think I am doing wrong?